# gRPC: How to apply QPS to ghz

Tags: grpc

We can read on [gRPC - Benchmarking](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/benchmarking/) that they use **QPS** to measure the performance:

> QPS – the messages/second rate when there are 2 clients and a total of 64 channels, each of which has 100 outstanding messages at a time sent using StreamingCall.

So, if my interpretation is correct:

- There are 2 gRPC **clients** (like 2 different running applications)
- Each client has 32 **channels**
- Each channel has 100 concurrent **outstanding messages** at a time. I think they refer to the count of concurrent calls and not the count of messages in a single stream.

**Question:** How to apply this definition to [ghz](https://ghz.sh/) to run a client?

Is it correct to run two processes with `ghz --connections=32 -c 3200` ?